# How to superimpose graph plots on top of each other (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

I have the following plots:

[image]

[image]

I need to put them in the same graph, together with a couple of other plots. I have the following code for each graph (I know it's not well-written, but it doesn't matter). Graph 1:

```
%%// Create a function handle of your function
f = @(x,a) 683.037971206./x + 1.96604876786e-4*x./a;
%%// Plot the data
x = linspace(500, 15000);
as = 9.5;
plot(x, bsxfun(f,x(:),as));
xlabel(gca, '$W_{to}/S_w$ (Pa)', ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
    'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
    'FontSize', 14, ...
    'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
    'FontAngle', 'normal')
ylabel(gca, {'$T_{to}/W_{to}$'}, ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
    'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
    'FontSize', 14, ...
    'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
    'FontAngle', 'normal')
```

Graph 2:

```
%%// Create a function handle of your function
f = @(x,a) 7.51619693312e-5*x;
%%// Plot the data
x = linspace(0, 15000);
as = 9.5;
plot(x, bsxfun(f,x(:),as));
xlabel(gca, '$W_{to}/S_w$ (Pa)', ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
    'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
    'FontSize', 14, ...
    'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
    'FontAngle', 'normal')
ylabel(gca, {'$T_{to}/W_{to}$'}, ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
    'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
    'FontSize', 14, ...
    'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
    'FontAngle', 'normal')
```

How would I go about superimposing these (and other) plots in the same graph. Also, how can I add a legend that identifies each of the plots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `hold on` after the first `plot` and before the second one.

Comment: I don't see the point to use `bsxfun' for multiplying function $f$ by scalar value $as$.